# How to render a list from firebase realtime database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I need to render a listing page where I can show the data items fetched from the firebase realtime database. I am using `@react-native-firebase/database` library to read the database. Also I want to enable pagination while fetching data.

I have created a function which basically fetches 10 list of item at a time and when user scroll downs it again fetches the next 10 item and update the previous state

```
setState(prevState => [...prevState,fetchedData])
```

I am using  `ref('database_url/data').on('value', snapshot => {...})` to read the database and it is working fine but when I update the database manually from Firebase, this listener triggers again and update the state again, and by updating I mean that it just push new updated items into previous state which is giving me duplication issues.

Although I can check the duplication before updating the state but that could affect the time and space complexity in case of millions of data.

And to avoid the listener to listen every changes I used `ref(/.../).once('value')` but in this case my data in the app is not getting updated when I update my firebase and I'm not asking my data to be updated in realtime but it should update when I call the function again right ??

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database'
import {useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native'

const UserListingPage = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    const [lastKeyItem, setLastKeyItem] = useState(null);
    const PAGINATION_LIMIT = 25
    
    const loadDataFromFirebase = () => {
        const reference = database().ref('/userListing/');
        let query = reference.orderByKey()
        
        if(!lastKeyItem){
            query = query.limitFirst(PAGINATION_LIMIT);
        }else{
            query = query.startAt(lastKeyItem).limitFirst(PAGINATION_LIMT);
        }
        query.once('value', snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                let fetchedData = snapshot.val();
                fetchedData = Object.entries(fetchedData);
                setUserData(prevState => [...prevState, ...fetchedData])
                setLastKeyItem(()=> fetchedData[0].key)
            }
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        loadDataFromFirebase()
    },[])
    
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={userData}
                renderItem = ({item}=> (<Text>{item.name}</Text>))
                onEndReached={loadDataFromFirebase}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

So what is the correct way to approach this use case in which I do not need realtime updates and wants to add pagination.

Thanks

Comment: 1) If you want to process the database updates more granularly, you can listen to the relevant `child_` events and update only the affected parts of your UI. 2) Calling `once` will give you a snapshot each time you call it. If that is not happening for you, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the first line inside your `loadDataFromFirebase` function, run in the debugger, and scroll to the end of the flatlist - does the breakpoint get triggered?

Comment: Yes it is trigerring, why ?

Comment: Also I have enabled offline persistence, so is that could be one of the reason ? And also I kill the app and restart the app while being online, still it does not fetch new child items.

Comment: Good to hear that the `loadDataFromFirebase` gets called at the right time when scrolling. I recommend stepping through the code line by line at that point, and checking the value of each variable on each line. Which is the first one that isn't what you expect it to be? The most suspicious one would be `lastKeyItem` of course. Does that have the value it should have?  Does it go into the right branch of the `if`?

Comment: Yes that part is working fine, because my pagination is working as I expect from it. The problem is that I am not getting updated data even I restart my app

Comment: Update : When I removed offline persistence from the app, it starts giving me the new data items

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const ListingPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Array to hold fetched data
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1); // Current page for pagination
  const itemsPerPage = 10; // Number of items per page

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const offset = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
      const response = await database()
        .ref('your_data_reference')
        .orderByKey()
        .startAt(offset.toString())
        .limitToFirst(itemsPerPage)
        .once('value');
      
      const dataSnapshot = response.val();
      if (dataSnapshot) {
        const newData = Object.values(dataSnapshot);
        setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...newData]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ListingPage;
```

Comment: Thanks @Hemil Rajpura for answering. In startAt() should we not need to pass the key of the child ?